# How do you install mods for Euro Truck Simulator 2?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I have downloaded some new mods for the game (like trucks and skins for the trucks) and I have put them into the mod folder. They don't seem to work, though.

**How do you install mods for this game?**

Answer (score 12):

To install mods for Euro Truck Simulator 2, follow these instructions;

- Browse to "My Documents\Euro Truck Simulator 2"
- Browse to "mod" - create the folder if it does not exist
- Place the ".scs" files into this folder (**not** a subfolder, ie: "My Documents\Euro Truck Simulator 2\mod\modfile.scs")
- Run the game, select your profile and click "Mod Manager"
- Double Click the mods that you want to enable and press "Confirm Changes"

Many of the instructions for installing mods just say "extract to this folder" but by doing that you end up creating another folder inside the mod folder. If the `.scs` files are in a sub folder than they will not load.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks I have done all that but it is saying I need the base file but I haven't got one anywhere do you know if I can download one or not.

Comment: the mods dont work on ets2 1.31 s....

Comment: @micke007 in ets 2 version 1.3+ you'll have to enable the mods manually. When choosing your profile, click on `edit profile`, on the right you'll see a list of the mods that you've put in the mods folder pick the ones you want, some may not work especially if they are old. The bad ones will crash your game.